# HTTP server will not listen on port 8000

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node js and programming. I've installed node js and am trying to run the following code in a .js file:

JS

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer( function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('Hello World!');
    server.listen(8000);
    console.log('Server running on port 8000');
});
```

Next, I ran the command node helloworld.js on the terminal. However, when I tried to open

```
http://localhost:8000
```

on chrome, it says google chrome cannot connect to "localhost:8000". What is the problem?

Comment: there is no response when I run it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you mis-typed an example code.

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
    response.end('Hello World!');
}); // <-----------
server.listen(8000);
console.log('Server running on port 8000');
```

Comment: Explanation: the first argument for [createServer()](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener) is «a function which is automatically added to the 'request' event» You cannot start the server after receiving the first request :)